# How to access "special" webcam's properties, like FOV or HDR

Tags: windows, webcam, directshow

Modern webcams, like Logitech, often have features available through their proprietary software, that I don't see available in DirectShow, or in the interface that shows up, the one that's typically used to setup webcam parameters in software like VirtualDub or OBS.

For example, Logitech Brio has "HDR" and "FOV" switch, and Logitech C930 has an FOV switch also. I assume it must be somehow possible to access these without the proprietary software, right? Or is it ONLY accessible through Logitech's software and there is no way to set it from code otherwise?